# plot() connects to display with ssh -X

Tags: python, matplotlib, ssh

I am working with a slow ssh-connection to a server. I want to save a figure like

```
#1
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,4])
plt.plot([1,3,4])
#...
plt.savefig("foo.jpg")
```

and show it with

```
feh foo.png
```

because `feh` is fast. Note there is no `plt.show()`

But the code `#1` is still very slow as long as I'm running `ssh -X`, because every `plot()`-instance connects to the display. If `-X` is left out it's fast, but then another connection is needed for the `feh`...

What is the reason for `plot()` connecting to the display and can it be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. In a `vscode` or `tmux` session with X-forwarding, in one terminal do `export DISPLAY=`  and here you can run the script fast, and do graphical stuff, like `feh`, in another terminal pane.

And for the record, `jpg` (2 sec) is considerably faster than `png` (4 sec) or `pdf` (6 sec) when shown with `feh` or `xpdf`.